# How do I press a button with no name attribute with WWW::Mechanize?

Tags: perl, www-mechanize

This is the button I want to click:

```
<input type="submit" value="Continue">
```

As you see it has no name at all to specify the order on it. I am using the [`WWW::Mechanize`](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize) module. I tried `$agent->submit();`, but it seems to not do the job, any help please?

Comment: Where is the button you are talking about? Is this a real question?

Comment: Read the docs.  "Submits the page, without specifying a button to click. Actually, no button is clicked at all."  Try 'click_button(value)' instead.

Comment: This is a perfectly legit question regarding WWW::Mech's form-submission functionality. Voting to reopen.

Comment: Yep this question should be re-opened. I can't believe 5 people closed what is an obvious question - trying to use the WWW::Mechanize module to do the same as a browser does when you click on the HTML input button... We need to down vote the closer clowns.

Comment: people are sheep; vote any arbitrary recent question for closing and you'll get 4 followers regardless of merit

Comment: omg this is 100% legit question I am not so good with perl.The button has no name maybe its an easy question instead answer me instead of closing.

Comment: Tried $mech->click_button(Continue); like someone asked and its not working.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to explicitely click the button to submit a form, [let Mechanize handle it implicitly](http://p3rl.org/WWW%3a%3aMechanize#mech-submit_form):

```
$mech->submit_form(
    with_fields => {
        username => 'foobar',
        password => '12345678',
    }
);
```

Run [mech-dump](http://p3rl.org/mech-dump) to see the relevant form input field names, for instance here in my example `username` and `password`.